# Hide/Show panel not showing - ACF

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I came across strange thing. I have been using ACF for a quite a long time now and I love this plugin, but I tried to use it for new project and when I create group of fields for my pages show/hide panel is not displaying and all fields are floating, i'm not sure what might be causing that unless there is some option which isn't selected.

http://grab.by/h50W

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of jQuery/javascript conflict. Try disabling all other plugins and enable them one after another to see which causes the issue.

Comment: nah its not JQ I tried that + plus no conflicts in Error panel